# Unable to find bug in countdown timer

Tags: python

```
# to make a timer
time_period = int(input('Enter length of counter: '))
import time
while time_period == 0:
    print(time_period)
    time_period = time_period - 1
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    print('Times up')
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `while time_period != 0`?

Comment: Usually, import statements come first in the code.

Comment: What happens when you run the code? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

time_period = int(input('Enter length of counter: '))

while time_period > 0: #here it should be greater than zero. Meaning as long as time_period is greater than 0, it will continue counting down.
    time_period -= 1
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('\r',time_period,end='')
else:
    print('Times up')
```